# Intellij 13.0.2 JUnit test do not run in Debug

Tags: junit, intellij-idea, xdebug

Intellij 13.0.2 JUnit test do not run in Debug

I have created several JUnit tests that run fine in Intellij, but when I try to Debug the same test, the files build and the test is not executed.  I look in the event log and all it says is All Files are up to date.  It does run NMake, but nothing more.

I don't know if this is related, but the View | Tool WIndows | Debug is disabled.

What do I need to do to Debug JUnit tests?

Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same problem with a Scala setup (and a ScalaTest rather than JUnit test).

Answer (score 1):

Select Run --> Run Configurations... from the IntelliJ window

Select JUnit on the left side.

On the right side there is a "Before Launch:" section for configuring the behavior before launching JUnit tests.

See also the [help page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-junit.html) for this.